# Can I use different brand calipers for the front brake calipers

Tags: brakes, brake-calipers

I need to replace the front brake calipers but can not find the same brand as the rear. Does this affect the car in any way or should i keep on looking for the same brand.

Comment: Is your replacement caliper a new or reman unit?  Reman units are often OEM units that have been remanufactured by a 3rd party.  So it's an OEM caliper with new parts in it.

Comment: @the_storyteller The OP asked about _calipers_, and your comment addresses _pads_.

Answer (score 1):

If you really can’t find the original make then you should at least have a pair of the same make of caliper at the front, even if they are a different make to the rear.

Do make sure that the pipe fittings match - experience has shown that there can be minor differences that are sufficient to cause problems and you do *not* want sudden problems with brakes. And if there are multiple circuits make sure of the connections so the circuits stay as they should.

Also make sure the pads are matched axle sets.

Otherwise there might be performance differences that surprise you,

Comment: I'd have to disagree. Hypothetically, if you're just replacing rears from OEM you'd actually go to the additional expense of replacing the fronts from OEM to rebuild aftermarket calipers?

Comment: @Enot the op needs to replace the fronts so I suggested a matching pair at the front ie same make left and right - not that they have to match the same make at the rear...

Comment: I must've misunderstood, my apologies.

Answer (score 0):

From personal experience: I've replaced front calipers, keeping the rears, and vice versa, depending on which ones were bad. As long as they get replaced in pairs I would not worry about whether they are different brands at all.

Answer (score 0):

If the builds were so precise that you need a matching pair then they would be sold that way.

From production line to production line the compounded tolerance could be substantially different on a left and right calliper from the same brand at the same factory let alone the same brand at two different factories.

New or rebuild they should be within the same parameters needed for equal braking.

That’s I figure anyways. I’ll find out if I’m right later today!

Comment: This doesn't address the question, which asks about using different brands front to back, not left to right.